Which define to use to distinguish between ARM processor and INTEL processor with QT?
For an application made in c++, QT 5.15, compiled to run on Windows and macOS (with Intel processor) we use the defines:
#if defined(Q_OS_MACOS)
    // do macOS code
    // ...
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN)
    // do Windows code
    // ...
#endif

but how to distinguish more accurately between macOS x86/ARM processor?

This sounds like an XY problem. Why do you need this? Presumably you can use one of the built-in compiler macros to figure out the architecture being compiled for.

yes, this is the question: which built-in compiler macros I could use to figure out the architecture being compiled for? The reason is than we use exactly the same sources to produce executable on Windows and on macOS, and now we would do the same to generate executable than also distinguish between macOS on Apple Silicon (M1, M2, ...) and macOS on Intel

If there is no builtin compiler macro regarding the architecture, can you define your own macro in the shell script which invoke the compiler ?

yes, probably using cmake I could define something at that level. I will try. I also will try the answer suggested in "duplicate question". Thanks to all!

The answer is even simpler: Qt defines Q_PROCESSOR_* macros for you. Q_PROCESSOR_ARM is set on my M1 macbook pro.

@Roberto these aren't built-in macro, that's Qt macros'. Bult-in are quite compiler-dependant and are described in particular compiler's documentation. Technique actualy demonstrated by Qt's header (qglobal.h?), you determine compiler first, then check if certain macrodefinition is present. Now if you need to know CPU model, that's trickier and is OS specific. Use libaries meant for that.

The chosen dupe target is actually kinda poor because it doesn't account for __arm64__, which is the one Apple uses for arm64...
